# VsCode notebook can't see pandas module

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, pip

In VsCode I have activated .venv environment in which I can see pandas module confirmed with `pip show pandas` command and I still see error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

(.venv) C:\PythonWs\testVsCodeNotebook>python --version
Python 3.10.8

How I can resolve this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

John Gordon points out that VsCode uses the wrong path to the python interpretation (.venv environment was created from VsCode palette and activated from command line). How I can fix it in VsCode?

PS. I put `import pandas as pd;` in a standalone python file and it works without any problem.
[image]

Comment: Show us the python interpreter you have selected in vs code.

Comment: @JohnGordon (.venv) C:\PythonWs\testVsCodeNotebook>python --version
Python 3.10.8

Comment: That's on the command line.  Show us **inside vs code** what interpreter you have slected.  And be sure to show the full path to the executable, not just the version number.

Comment: @JohnGordon I added snapshot in post (let me know if it is not what you expected)

Comment: Hmm.  Show us the output of this from vs code: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250647/discussion-between-alexeip-and-john-gordon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use jupyter notebook, you need to choose kernel, click the following button in picture:

[image]

You can also read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_create-or-open-a-jupyter-notebook) for more details.